# Java mail stuck on opening Folder.open

Tags: java, multithreading, email, jakarta-mail

My application stuck sometimes while opening a folder in a POP3 connection. It happens only one time in 2-3 weeks. We check the account every 5 minutes and when it get stucked its not possible to connect again because we lock the username and unlock when the connection is finished.

It is a multi-thread application and the other threads still works.

It connect in a private email server.

I check with VisualVM to get where it is stucked and here is the thread stacktrace:

```
"Monitor-EMAIL-925" - Thread t@16629
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
- locked <265d84f2> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.readResponse(Protocol.java:714)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.simpleCommand(Protocol.java:689)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:114)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:260)
- locked <1580e275> (a com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:208)
- locked <1245cbd5> (a com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder)
at com.xxx.mail.MonitorEmail.processarPasta(MonitorEmail.java:377)
at com.xxx.mail.MonitorEmail.run(MonitorEmail.java:341)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

I'm using javamail-1.4.7 version.

The method com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.readResponse(Protocol.java:714) has a call to a deprecated value of DataInputStream:

```
/**
 * Read the response to a command.
 */
private Response readResponse() throws IOException {
    String line = null;
    try {
        line = input.readLine(); // XXX - readLine is deprecated
    } catch (InterruptedIOException iioex) {
        /*
         * If we get a timeout while using the socket, we have no idea what
         * state the connection is in. The server could still be alive, but
         * slow, and could still be sending data. The only safe way to
         * recover is to drop the connection.
         */
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException cex) {
        }
        throw new EOFException(iioex.getMessage());
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        /*
         * If we get an error while using the socket, we have no idea what
         * state the connection is in. The server could still be alive, but
         * slow, and could still be sending data. The only safe way to
         * recover is to drop the connection.
         */
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException cex) {
        }
        throw new EOFException(ex.getMessage());
    }

    if (line == null) {
        traceLogger.finest("<EOF>");
        throw new EOFException("EOF on socket");
    }
    Response r = new Response();
    if (line.startsWith("+OK"))
        r.ok = true;
    else if (line.startsWith("-ERR"))
        r.ok = false;
    else
        throw new IOException("Unexpected response: " + line);
    int i;
    if ((i = line.indexOf(' ')) >= 0)
        r.data = line.substring(i + 1);
    return r;
}
```

Comparing against javamail-1.5.2 this method is different and just return a Response:

```
public Response readResponse() 
    throws IOException, ProtocolException {
    return new Response(this);
}
```

Has anyone already had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be some sort of network or server glitch.  You probably want to configure timeouts so your application can recover from problems such as this.

Comment: Im gonna set this two "properties mail.pop3.timeout" and "mail.pop3.connectiontimeout". If the connection timed out when opening the folder I will accept your answer.